# Force push process to swap

Tags: swap

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on Chromebook. There is couple semi-unneed processes like Google Chrome running in background which I can't just mask via 'chmod -x' or kill since they respawn again (anyway, rarely I'm switching back to ChromeOS therefore can't just remove them).

In short, I need somehow to swap any particular process. Is this possible? Well, like 'vmtouch'-reverse.